# Oracle connection string without tnsnames.ora file

Tags: .net, asp.net, oracle, connection-string, oracleclient

I am using the .NET framework with the System.Data.OracleClient namespace.  I have the oracle 11 client installed on my computer.  I do not want to use the tnsnames.ora file to store connection information.

Could someone please tell me what the connection string would look like if I did not want to use the tnsnames.ora file?  I will be storing the connection string in a web.config file of a Web Application Project.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle

This is a great resource

> SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))
>   (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;

is what you want i believe...

Comment: It should be: "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"

Answer (score 31):

Starting with 10g clients, you can use the [EZCONNECT](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT) feature, which does not require to edit the TNSNAMES.ORA file : `username/password@servername:port/instance`. For instance :

```
Data Source=localhost:1521/XE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=scott;Password=tiger;Unicode=True
```

Comment: Oh thank you thank you!