# connect to remote oracle database via visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, oracle

I have installed the oracle develop tools, odp.net blah blah etc for visual studio 2010 to see, but I have no idea how to connect to the remote oracle server? Maybe I can do it via code, but I was thinking that I could go to "Data Connections" in Visual Studio and add a connection to the oracle database? Yet I have no idea what to put in data source name, etc as all I have is an ip, port, and some name of the database or something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820440/oracle-connection-string-without-tnsnames-ora-file

Comment: that does not help. I don't know what to put into the form fields in the add connection form in visual studio.

Comment: if you already know the host, port and ORACLE_SID/Service_Name, all that is left are userid and password. This sounds like : grab a manual.

Answer (score 0):

How about this http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/14/10227071/how-to-connect-remote-oracle-database-in-vbnet.aspx ? I don't know about the tool you use, so I might be a little off.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just got it solved. Pretty straightforward by the end.

Under the username and password, enter the credentials you have.

In the 'Data source name' field, enter: `<--host address-->/<--server_name-->`

Answer (score 0):

From vs2010 menu, select Tools --> Connect to database

Under 'Data Source' click change and select 'oracle database'

Click ok

Enter server name, username and password.

Test Connection, if good, click ok