# Oracle connection string in web.config throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have below connection string in my Web.config:

```
<add name="OracleString" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" ConnectionString ="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;"/>
```

when I try to retrieve the same using below code

```
ConnectionStringSettings connectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleString"];

DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionStringSettings.ProviderName);

DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
//set the connection string
conn.ConnectionString = connectionStringSettings.ConnectionString;
```

its throwing exception:

> Keyword :description is not supported

Comment: my mistake I have not copied the connectionString attribute- while posting the question .....but that is not the case

Comment: The Microsoft version of the Oracle client has been deprecated for some time now.  The ODP.Net client from Oracle is now preferred (referenced in Marcos Lommez's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Patterns and Standarts are a great think.

Try to change your connection string for something like the indicated in [Microsoft's Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92ceczx1(v=vs.85).aspx) and I am sure that it will work

In your case I think this will do the trick:

```
<add name="OracleString"
  connectionString="Server=tcp:MyHost,MyPort;Database=MyOracleSID;UserID=myUsername;Password=myPassword"
  providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

Edit:
After some research I found out that the type of connection you are using is possible for oracle, but **I believe you forgot Data Source or Server before your Description**, something like this should do the trick

```
<add name="OracleString" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;"/>
```

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820440/oracle-connection-string-without-tnsnames-ora-file)

Comment: when I used above approach - am getting Exception - ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: Check your Oracle installation like is explained in this post http://forums.asp.net/t/503406.aspx?TNS+No+Listener

Answer (score 0):

Coder2014, some days ago I´ve a problem with my web.Config. When pasting the connectionString to the web.config, the string was using a different enconding.
To verify that, i used the http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ to validate the file.

If is not your case, maybe you should use the tnsnames.ora. Take a look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/

Answer (score 0):

Based on similar posts for the error message format

> Keyword ______ is not supported

The problem seems to lie in the engine not recognizing what "Description" is (at the beginning of your connection string).

I do not think your connection string should like that.
You copied and pasted what you had in your TNSnames.ora.

An example of a oracle connection string is:

```
<add name="oracleConnectionString"
     connectionString="Server=yourDBServer; User ID=userIdToConnectWith; Password=userIdPassword; Unicode=True"
     providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

From your sample above, I am not sure - but I think "MyOracleSID" would go in place of "yourDBServer".

Comment: when I used above approach - am getting Exception - ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: are you able to connect to this database in any other way ? Sql Plus ? Toad / PL/SQL Developer ?

Comment: I am able to connect to sql developer

Comment: You have an oracle database you are trying to connect to. Do you succeed in connecting to it in any way? Do you know its server name ?

Comment: If so, what is the name of the Oracle DB you connect to, whenever you successfully do so ? You need to use that very same name in the connection string at `Server=______`. If you succeed connecting to it via a GUI program, than the server should be up and receiving ORA-12541 does not make sense